# How to solve "width: 100% child bigger than flexbox parent when has horizontal scroll" without seting overflow: hidden;

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Flexbox child bigger than flexbox parent.
[image]
I know that we can solve the problem with seting `overflow: hidden;` in parent. But we need solve this problem without seting `overflow: hidden;`:

```js
const Child = () => <div className="h-16 w-24 ml-2 flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0 bg-gray-700">d</div>;
```

```html
<main className="w-168 flex p-4 bg-green-700">
  <div className="w-56 flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0 bg-red-900">child</div>
  <div className="w-full p-4 bg-blue-300"> <!-- we can solve the problem with seting overflow: hidden; on this tag -->
    <div className="w-full flex flex-no-wrap overflow-x-auto bg-gray-500">
      <Child />
      <Child />
      <Child />
      <Child />
      <Child />
      <Child />
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

```css
.h-16 {
  height: 4rem;
}
.w-24 {
  width: 6rem;
}
.w-168 {
  width: 42rem;
}
.w-56 {
  width: 14rem;
}
.w-full {
  width: 100%;
}
.overflow-hidden {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.overflow-x-auto {
  overflow-x: auto;
}
.ml-2 {
  margin-left: 0.5rem;
}
.p-4 {
  padding: 1rem;
}
.flex {
  display: flex;
}
.flex-grow-0 {
  flex-grow: 0;
}
.flex-shrink-0 {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
.flex-no-wrap {
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
.bg-gray-700 {
  background-color: #4a5568;
}
.bg-green-700 {
  background-color: #2f855a;
}
.bg-red-700 {
  background-color: #c53030;
}
.bg-blue-300 {
  background-color: #90cdf4;
}
```

Comment: Try `min-width:0;`

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem with set `min-width:0;` on parent.